# Best way to dynamically define a type to a function that returns an utility object based on the properties of object passed as parameter

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function that normalizes an input representing a series of potential filters to be applied to a query.
A filter is an object that can contain some attributes from a list of predefined attributes, and each one can contain a single string or an array of strings.
One example of filter can be expressed by the following type:

```
interface QueryFilter {
  id?: string | string[];
  sku?: string | string[];
  name?: string | string[];
}
```

My function will create a utility object that will be of the following type:

```
interface QueryFilterNormalized {
  hasId: () => boolean;
  getId: () => string[];
  hasSku: () => boolean;
  getSku: () => string[];
  hasName: () => boolean;
  getName: () => string[];
}
```

The normalization will make each property from `QueryFilter` not present in the object to return an empty array, and each property that contains only a single string will be considered an array of a single element instead.

Here is the my first attempt to build the function and create the types:

```
type QueryObject = {
  [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
};

interface QueryFilter extends QueryObject {
  id?: string | string[];
  sku?: string | string[];
  name?: string | string[];
}

type QueryObjectNorm<T extends QueryObject> = {
  [Property in keyof T as `has${Capitalize<
    string & Property
  >}`]-?: () => boolean;
} & {
  [Property in keyof T as `get${Capitalize<
    string & Property
  >}`]-?: () => string[];
};

function norm<T extends QueryObject>(object: T): QueryObjectNorm<T> {
  const obj: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  for (const i in object) {
    const key = i.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + i.slice(1);
    let querystr: string[] = [];
    const value = object[i];
    if (value) {
      querystr = querystr.concat(value);
    }
    obj['has' + key] = () => querystr.length > 0;
    obj['get' + key] = () => querystr;
  }
  return obj as QueryObjectNorm<T>;
}

const queryObject = {
  id: 'A',
  sku: ['B', 'C']
}

const t = norm<QueryFilter>(queryObject);
  console.log(t.getId())
  console.log(t.getSku())
  console.log(t.hasName())
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiA8gIwFYQMbCgXigG8AoKKAbQGsIQAuKAZ2EQEsA7AcwF0Hm2uUAD5MWHThW7CocdgBMIAMw4Q5AbhIBfDSQ7AkigIbZo8JCABirADb7EUCAA998xrATJ0WXMTJRWcgD8fGKCIvzikhrkjFRwwaICnNIRXFF+7IYAthAJqcnhoRLcGpokJKCQ7uZeOMAAcgD2iFkAPAAqDs4QrtWemHUAfAS+5BQACoiNkIig-uxQNCCNilCdhm4ABgAWGwAkRADChmCswIbWrABeEK1+MUVQAGRQk9NIoH6DmpvcALQJAAUAEoCMM0I1GtYIIZ2KVnqNKG8ZnMOItaCs1lANlBNpwIMADsdTudLjc7uQHkkEciPiAvj9-kDQfhhvl0tpyopZLhWI0Fuxmm1Ok4XHI3GZ+t5gINAY0BrgGO1gQxJagFQ0hR1hqRyNh+cwoPKMAwiJQliEkrxsewQFBNCMiJzyIpmlBAfr2IbWPMjRrQbrKZ7DUsRqwAHTYXaIACCwEBAAZgeHgI0AKpgGbHRgQEFQADU-nDjEuJkBAEZgdFKdC8ABHDwgfiWyJSQjpSlQYN4ABuFwQI2NdQorBK938q0BfesCAD4-IDfM-BGi+Q-Ej-Owhnj09n1fIZU7xooAHJdowTwX0SA2+6WcNV02WOHoVxgNsoMME-u-RhT-jgEvQsllvPNWSgR9+GrQ8oEQAk4EQBZjWxCVG1qXAmhabVSnKbsILQjVHT8AIGBPGMTwAGj8WI4AYU8ACFKKgE9DhPbgtFwg08DwQhBSwtUrFsJBZUfdDgCrPxgyhCAX0aThAWAcMAIASTkEFgUkg1pNk+TFIAgBlOJ1M0r1tOsOSFPDc96myXNgQ08ggA)

It works only for the properties that are present in the object. In the example above, `t.hasName()` results in an error for that reason. Types are being created correct though, but I am not sure if they are as neat as they should be.

Then my second approach was not to have the QueryFilter interface anymore and have an array of filters, interating this array instead of the object, and creating the types using the array as the standpoint.

Here is my second attempt:

```
type QueryObject = {
  [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined;
};

type ObjectArr<T extends Readonly<Array<string>>> = {
  [key in T[number]]: string | string[];
};

type QueryObjectNorm<T> = {
  [Property in keyof T as `has${Capitalize<
    string & Property
  >}`]-?: () => boolean;
} & {
  [Property in keyof T as `get${Capitalize<
    string & Property
  >}`]-?: () => string[];
};

function norm<T extends QueryObject>(
  keys: readonly (keyof T)[],
  object: Partial<T>,
): QueryObjectNorm<T> {
  const obj: { [key: string]: any } = {};
  for (const i of keys) {
    let key = i as string;
    key = key.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + key.slice(1);
    let querystr: string[] = [];
    const value = object[i];
    if (value) {
      querystr = querystr.concat(value);
    }
    obj['has' + key] = () => querystr.length > 0;
    obj['get' + key] = () => querystr;
  }
  return obj as QueryObjectNorm<T>;
}


const queryObject = {
  id: 'A',
  sku: ['B', 'C']
}

const queryFilter = ['id', 'sku', 'name'] as const;

const t = norm<ObjectArr<typeof queryFilter>>(queryFilter, queryObject);
console.log(t.getId())
console.log(t.getSku())
console.log(t.hasName())
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-KSaK0lNBm0AN22CGidvqFFY3G75FYEzes98CEjRxxA5q-Gih+Q-CzPmw7nz293a6gmn3dooAHIFowX1AG-EpIRKfh2lPIcWAzAEuGAOYoHaAt72fF8kWAT9v1oX8KS+AD+0Hfhu0fcgJWAOBEBGO0pmcI1aiMU0WjaUpyhIKc8CAgVcA6WJWDkBgX2MF9lWOKg4AYV8ACEeKgF8VhfbgtHKBjMJqAAxVhfAcRBxxfdjRJfRh+M09h3HSCBJNIqAGJ0WS8EINlqOY4AgnMPQIHGOTkEU5SkEiN4gNclTFWcij6i7ejrX+CBQK8Tg3mADMEIASTkT4PiC4MQrCiKooQgBlfiEqSxgUt8cLIozd8Gn02sPkSoA)

Using this approach I have the correct output and correct types. I am not convinced though I have the most neat solution especially around type creating and type casting.
Just so we are clear there will be different filters for different queries, hence I am creating an generic function that will create the utility object according to the input.
Any suggestions on how to improve it?
Thanks!

Comment: What in particular about your second solution concerns you?  The only type assertion (this is the preferred term over "casting" in TypeScript) you might drop is `i as string` since you can just annotate `keys: readonly (string & keyof T)[],` if you care.  Everything else seems reasonable to me (there's no way the compiler will be able to follow the implementation logic to verify that `obj` will be a valid `QueryObjectNorm<T>`, so you might as well assert). Personally I don't see anything here that needs an answer other than . How should we proceed?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz, first for the correction on the terminology (new to TS, always good to know), and for the change you proposed that leave us with one less type assertion, which is great. My concern is mainly on that, I had to create an empty object and give it a type `{ [key: string]: any }` only because I can't build the final result at once using dot notation (`obj.hasId` instead of `obj['hasId']` and so on), forcing the type assertion on `return obj as QueryObjectNorm<T>`. I thought maybe the last assertion would be unecessary if the result was built different, as well as the obj var typing